# 3-by-2 Multi Table

Tags: tables, captions

I would like to make a Table that contains six individual tables in a 3-by-2 format in it (see attached picture :) ). I would like to add a caption under every single one of the six tables but cannot figure it out. Additionally I would like to be able to use it in a resizebox config. My code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

% Newly defined command:
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}} 

% My Code
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I simply concatenated the individual tables ... There must be a better way. [image]

Comment: Do not use resizebox on tables as it will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document. Regarding the individual captiobs: you might be interested in the subcaption or the subfig package.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you, I know that I shouldn't use resizebox, but I wanted to know whether there would be a difference. I know that there is subcaption, but I would like to increase the distance between the individual tables... any clue ? :)

Comment: The horizontal distance between the subtables can be adjusted by chosing the appropriate with of `subtable` or for example by adding `\hfill` between two adjacent subtable environments. A lot also depends on teh documentclass, paper size, margins and font size. So please make your code compilable.

Comment: I have updated the code now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are satisfied with the following suggestion based upon `subcaption`'s `subtable` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

% Newly defined command:
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}} 
% My Code

\begin{table}
\caption{common caption for all tables}
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{individual caption}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{individual caption} 
    \end{subtable}
    \medskip

    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{individual caption}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{individual caption} 
    \end{subtable}
    \medskip

    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{individual caption}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \specialcell{White \\ Noise} & \specialcell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \specialcell{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{individual caption} 
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Two unrelated suggestions that yould help make your life easier: The `\makecell` command from the eponymous package provides a similar result as your `\specialcell` command while allowing to define the horizontal alignment through an optional argument. Instead of using `p` for the first column and manual linebreaks, you could also switch to `m` type columns and automatic linebreaks.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{common caption for all tables}
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c|c}
        & \makecell{White \\ Noise} & \makecell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        \makecell[l]{NRMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        \makecell[l]{NMSE \\ Fit [\%]} & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{individual caption}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm} c|c}
        & \makecell{White \\ Noise} & \makecell{Pink \\ Noise} \\
        \hline
        NRMSE  Fit [\%] & 92.802 & 89.530 \\
        \hline
        NMSE  Fit [\%] & 99.482 & 98.904 \\
        \hline
        $R^2$ & 0.995 & 9.989 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{individual caption} 
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem ! And also thanks for the \makecell edit ;)

Comment: leandriis, i can't find the eponymous package ? What is that ?

Comment: Perhaps it is not installed. Did you try with your package manager?

Comment: @Bernard No, I did not, however it must also work in overleaf, right ? So I should just add \usepackage{eponymous}, but overleaf cannot recognize it ?

Comment: `\usepackage{makecell}`, to be exact.

Comment: @leandriis: soryy for bring fussy, but don't you think it's rather the command which is the eponymous of the package?

Comment: @Bernard Wow, added a the word 'eponymous' to my vocabulary, haha. Sorry guys !

Answer (score 4):

With a little bit different subtables layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.84}}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=3ex]{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
% My Code
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{?}
\label{tab:tables}
\centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}} 
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
    \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular} 
\caption{First}
    \end{subtable}
\hfil
    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}}
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
   \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular}
\caption{second}
    \end{subtable}  

    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}}
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
    \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Third}
    \end{subtable}
\hfil
    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}}
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
    \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Fourth}
    \end{subtable} 

    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}}
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
    \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Fifth}
    \end{subtable}
\hfil
    \begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
                & {\makecell{White\\ Noise}}
                            & {\makecell{Pink\\ Noise}} \\
    \midrule
NRMSE Fit [\%]  & 92.802    & 89.530                    \\
        \hline
NMSE Fit [\%]   & 99.482    & 98.904                    \\
    \midrule
$R^2$           & 0.995     & 9.989
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Sixt}
    \end{subtable}   
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: thank you! I might consider it, too !

Comment: @aladin, you are welcome. Just now I litle bit improve tables layout (better centering, better column headers).

Comment: Thank you! Looks much better now:)

Answer (score 3):

I have the feeling that using such six tables are not the best way to present your information. There is much redundancy and scattering of information.

One bigger table can be used. You can spare some space in the tables for better visualization and mention the details inside the text and in the single caption above the table. For example, `NRMSE` and `NMSE` are known terms in the field, you can omit the words `fit` and `(%)` and mention them in text or caption above. Each of the previous subcaptions can now fill a table cell in the first column. Column type `X` is more suitable for these.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{My bigger caption for the whole table ..}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X *6{c} @{}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{White noise} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Pink noise} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
  & NRMSE & NMSE & $R^2$ & NRMSE & NMSE & $R^2$  \\ \midrule
Caption 1 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\ 
Caption 2 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\
Caption 3 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\
Caption 4 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\
Caption 5 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\ 
Caption 6 (Much longer text will go here ...) & 92.802 & 99.482 & 0.995 & 89.530 & 98.904 & 9.989 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I have to give you credit for that. I was thinking myself that maybe I will change the style of the table completely, I think your solution is really great and suits my needs better ,so I will use it for my Thesis ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: one more question has come to my mind as I'm just using your structure :) How to put the text ''Caption 1 ...' in center of the respective column ? And how could i add 'Model Output DoF' above it in the same space where White Noise Pink Noise etc. is ?

Comment: To center captions column, just use `>{\centering}X` instead of `X`. For the second request, if I understood you correctly, just put _Model Output DoF_ before the first `&` and after `\toprule`.

Comment: thanks ! You helped me out a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    A11 & A12 & A13 & A14 \\
    \hline
    A21 & A22 & A23 & A24 \\
    \hline
    A31 & A32 & A33 & A34 \\
    \hline
    A41 & A42 & A43 & A44 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \centerline{(a) First Table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      B11 & B12 & B13 & B14 \\
      \hline
      B21 & B22 & B23 & B24 \\
      \hline
      B31 & B32 & B33 & B34 \\
      \hline
      B41 & B42 & B43 & B44 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \centerline{(b)Second Table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      C11 & C12 & C13 & C14 \\
      \hline
      C21 & C22 & C23 & C24 \\
      \hline
      C31 & C32 & C33 & C34 \\
      \hline
      C41 & C42 & C43 & C44 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \centerline{(c) Second Table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

please refer to the following [link](https://www.physicsread.com/two-and-more-tables-side-by-side-in-latex/) were the author adding subtable using minipage. I use some part of the code from here

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable for a fast proof!

Comment: Thank you for quick advice. Have made the necessary changes